# Which one is correct "Applicant to" or "Applicant for"?

Tags: prepositions

I am unable to find which one is correct.
"Applicant to" or "Applicant for" University.

I am applicant to/for university.

Comment: What are you actually trying to say? What is the full sentence this will be used in? As is, there's probably a better way to phrase this.

Comment: _I am applicant for/to your university_

Comment: It'd be much more likely that a native speaker would say "I'm applying to your university".

Comment: I Name Surname, applicant to/for xYZ university, ....

Comment: Why would you classify yourself as an applicant like that? That's pretty non-standard in my experience. You could call yourself an applicant to any university on the planet and it means nothing because you've not been admitted.

Answer (score 1):

"To" is correct in your example.

> I am *an* applicant **to** your university.

That being said, the idiomatic phrasing is to say:

> I am applying to your university.

You can also say

> I am applying *for* admittance *to* your university.

Comment: Thanks,
Which one is correct?
get a better insight into me / get a better insight about me
Sorry I am unable to post new question for 40 minutes

Comment: Then you will have to wait. Answering questions in comments is strongly discouraged. If you are in a big hurry and need help proofreading, I suggest you find a site that specializes in proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

> You are an applicant **to** an institution.
>   I am an applicant **to** King's College.

and

> You are an applicant **for** a position.
>   I am an applicant **for** full-time study.